# XSLT if not equal strings

Tags: xslt

I am trying to compare the value of these elements. I have roles that can be found both under policy and group elements. If role is printed out through policy element, I don't want to print it again when I am working through group element. Rather print only those roles under group element that haven't been before handled and printed out by policy element.

This is how I am approaching it, but somehow the NOT operator is not working and prints out all roles under group element:

```
<xsl:variable name="roleGroup" select="service/group/name" />
<xsl:variable name="rolePolicy" select="service/group/policy/name" />

<xsl:for-each select="service/group/name">
            <xsl:if test="not($roleGroup = $rolePolicy)">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>            
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The XML structure:

```
<service>
<group>
<name>Admins</name>
</group>
<group>
<name>Basic users</name>
</group>
</service>

<service>
<group>
<name>Admins</name>
<policy>
<name>Superusers</name>
</policy>
<policy>
<name>Support</name>
</policy>
</group>
</service>
```

The output is like this:

```
Group; Role Thru Policy
Admins; Superusers
Admins; Support
Admins;
Basic users;
```

But I want it like this, without the second Admins group:

```
Group; Role Thru Polic
Admins; Superusers
Admins; Support
Basic users;
```

Because the Admins group is already in the output.

I appreciate if any one could tell me where the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us an example (or rather examples, if you have different scenarios) of the input, and the expected output of each case.

Comment: Please notice the edit and more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You say "If role is printed out through policy element, I don't want to print it again when I am working through group element."

But your condition `test="not($roleGroup = $rolePolicy)"` depends only on two variables declared *outside* the loop - if it's true for any iteration of the loop, then it's going to be true for every iteration.

As I can't see your source XML, I can't tell you what exactly what the condition should be, but I would guess `test="not(. = $rolePolicy)"`

**POSTSCRIPT**

Frankly, I find it a little depressing that pointing out your bug wasn't enough to enable you to fix it. I'm very reluctant to write code for people who clearly don't understand the language well enough yet to understand why the code works, and I strongly suggest that you need to do more reading before you do more coding. But in the meantime, try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="rolePolicy" select="service/group/policy/name" />

<xsl:for-each select="service/group/name[not(. = $rolePolicy)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>            
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Actually I did that way too, but that gives the same result. Please notice my question again as I edited it with more explanations.

Comment: You might have edited your code, but it still has the same error.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to ignore (not to print) in the output the group names under service/group that are also under service/group/policy. Sorry that I can't explain this better :(

Comment: Thanks for being frank and thanks for the help. Unfortunately doesn't help that either. I have tried in fact different ways, with variables within and also outside the loop as well as by writing the nested elements directly without any variables. Still get the same result. Probably there is something in the complicated XML file that I am not seeing well. I should check that more.